# Select an Element by it´s value when value has HTML Characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, html-entities

I´m stucked with the following Problem at the moment and I´m running out of ideas. I´ve a **select box** with different **options which have HTML characters in their value field**:

```
<select>    
<option value="Zinksulfat" selected="selected">Zinksulfat</option>
<option value="Zypressen&ouml;l" selected="selected">Zypressenöl</option>
<option value="Wirkstoff&quot;Mit'Anf&uuml;hrungszeichen" selected="selected">Wirkstoff"Mit'Anführungszeichen</option>
</select>
```

For HTML encoding of variables in jQuery I´m using this simple function:

```
function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace('ü', '&uuml;').replace('ö', '&ouml;');
}
```

Now I try to **get the option object by it´s value** ("select" is the select box):

```
// Set the element value
var elementValue = 'Wirkstoff"Mit'Anführungszeichen'; // Invalid I know - only for description purpose
    elementValue = htmlEntities(elementValue);

return select.find('option[value="'+elementValue+'"]')[0];
```

So for elements without HTML characters it works like a charm (eg. "Zinksulfat"). But for the elements with HTML Characters it doesn´t work. although the value in "elementValue" and the value field are exactly the same I receive "**undefined**".

Has anybody an idea what magic thing has to be done so that I can use HTML characters in the selector?

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Comment: just escape the string correctly.refer http://jsfiddle.net/769gp0nn/

Comment: My answer was overkill (deleted).. Just format the string correctly as @VJ Sai suggests :)

Comment: @VJ Sai: Post your comment as answer (before someone else does)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie : posted it as answer.Thanks mate for reminding.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need your function at all. It is simply a case of getting the string correct (escaping any single-quotes in a single-quoted string). The HTML encoding translations are done for you by jQuery:

```
var elementValue = 'Wirkstoff"Mit\'Anführungszeichen';
$("select").find('option[value="'+elementValue+'"]').css("color", "red");
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/prnxbdp8/

Select another option in the dropdown to see that the match is now red.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution after some more tests - maybe it helps somebody else. Instead of using the select.find() method it works with .filter() method:

**Does not work with HTML characters:**

```
return select.find('option[value="'+elementValue+'"]')[0];
```

**Works:**

```
// Find and return the option element from select box
var foundOption = select.find('option').filter(function() {
    return (htmlEntities(this.value) == elementValue);
}).show();

return foundOption[0];
```

Comment: That is similar to what I had originally (check my edits), but `htmlEntities` is not needed at all as that translation is done for you by jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with escaping the string. Refer to the fiddle to get the solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/769gp0nn/

```
function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace('ü', '&uuml;').replace('ö', '&ouml;');
}

var elementValue = 'Wirkstoff"Mit\'Anführungszeichen';

console.log($("select").find('option[value="'+elementValue+'"]')[0]);
```

Comment: Note: `\"` is *not* require inside a string delimited with `'`.

Answer (score -1):

Its really easy to fix. You need to escape the elementValue.

just do:

```
elementValue = htmlEntities(elementValue);

function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace('ü', '&uuml;').replace('ö', '&ouml;');
}
```

And it should work. https://jsfiddle.net/8pf9vooc/

Comment: It's one thing to post answer that does what it says, but your example does not do that. You do not even include the `elementValue` in your JSFiddle.

Comment: That´s a misunderstanding... not the escape function is the problem. The selector including HTML characters is...